# Explination for why map works but mongodb $each doesn't

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

Can someone please explain why one method of adding arrays to my database works and the other doesn't. Really lost as to what the difference is. I'm using `aldeed/node-simple-schema` and `collection2`.

Example: `Schema`

```
'topFiveSkills': { type: Array, optional: true },
'topFiveSkills.$': { type: String, optional: true }
```

Example: 'Working example'

```
topFiveSkills = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

this.state.topFiveSkills.map((skill) => {
  ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
    $push: { 'topFiveSkills': skill }
  });
})
```

Example: 'Doesn't work'

```
topFiveSkills = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
  $push: { 'topFiveSkills': { $each: [topFiveSkills] }}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see is that you apply a nested array on your $each example. Try below:

```
topFiveSkills = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
  $push: { 
   'topFiveSkills': { 
     $each: topFiveSkills 
   }
  }
});
```

*Note that I'm putting my object key/vals on a separate line. Its exactly for this reason, but ofcourse not a critical thing.*

Comment: I get the same thing. Within the collection it inserts `topFiveSkills: []` . There's no data and no error.

Comment: Have you checked the profileCandidateCollectionId? If its null its silently ignoring the action.

Comment: Yep. I've also used validation to make sure it's an array. It passes validation but when I try to update it now returns `not an array`. I think it's a.bug. I've reported it, so I'll post the outcome if there is one.